# CgLib Enhancer private Constructor

Tags: java, bytecode, cglib

I'm trying to create a proxy with cglib for a class that only has a private constructor. I can't change the visibility, as it's a library method.

I found [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.cglib.devel/1380), and followed the instrcutions to override the `filterConstructors` method, but when cglib tries to call it I get an `java.lang.IllegalAccessError`.

Can I bypass this limitation somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Cglib works by subclassing. The cglib class can therefore never access the constructor of the proxied class.

What you can tryto do is to redefine the existing class. For this, you can use a library such as [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy).